# Google Sheets: Conditional Formatting Based On a Cell - If Contains String

Tags: regex, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, is it possible to have conditional formatting on cell A1 that changes the colour if B1 **contains** the string "Hello World!", but **not necessarily exactly** the exact same?

Comment: "but not necessarily exactly the exact same" - what does that even mean...

Comment: contains the same string but, e.g. may be "Hello World 1": this is not the same as "Hello World" but still contains the keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B1), "hello world")
```